# Application access Policy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, policy

If we scope the Application access Policy to specific mail enabled group and grant access only to the member of the group there are chances for any userid can be added to the group and leverage full access to the mailbox. What level of security controls can be added to prevent this??

Comment: Please check this MS link if it can helpful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps

Comment: sorry it is not helpful,  I need to know how to restrict owner of a mail enabled security group to add members in that group. What are the settings and control mechanism available to restrict owner of the group??

Comment: you can add or remove owner of mail enabled security group but you can not restrict owner to add member to mail enabled security group .By default, the person who creates a group is the owner. All groups must have at least one owner. Please check this document for reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-mail-enabled-security-groups

Answer (score 0):

Use the **New-ApplicationAccessPolicy** cmdlet to restrict or deny access to a specific set of mailboxes by an application that uses APIs (Outlook REST, Microsoft Graph, or Exchange Web Services (EWS)). These policies are complementary to the permission scopes that are declared by the application.

While scope-based resource access like Mail.Read or Calendar.Read is effective to ensure that the application can only read email or events within a mailbox and not do anything else, application access policies allow admins to enforce limits that are based on a list of mailboxes. For example, apps developed for one country shouldn't have access to data from other countries. Or, or a CRM integration application should only access calendars in the Sales organization and no other departments.

Reference: [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy (ExchangePowerShell) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps)